# Move table section vertical on the left side of table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've created table with some data and sections. By default, the head of the table (section) is placed on top of the table. I wonder if it is possible to move the section vertical on the left side of the table as shown belown picture link.

http://i48.tinypic.com/2dcg0fp.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView headers on the left side of sections (like Spotlight)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180272/uitableview-headers-on-the-left-side-of-sections-like-spotlight)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to move the section on the left side of the tabelview. But you can customize it. You can customize tableview. Say you want to create section1, then take a simple view and draw a thin line or use an image of 1px to draw line at regular intervals.