# How to achieve an advanced table view header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a grouped `UITableView`. Now unlike the default table view header my header should be *next* to the individual cells:

Standard:

```
[Header Cell]
[Item 1]
[Item 2]
```

What I need

```
+-------+----------------+
|       |  Item 1a       |
|  h1   +----------------+
|       |  Item 1b       |
+ - - - +----------------+
|          Item 1c       |
+------------------------+
|       |  Item 2a       |
|  h2   +----------------+
|       |  Item 2b       |
+------------------------+
|       |  Item 3a       |
|  h3   +----------------+
|       |  -placeholder- |
+-------+----------------+
```

Some remarks:

- Group H1 has three items
- Group H2 has two items
- Group H3 has just one item (I have to insert a placeholder cell so that the header cell can have the full height of two item-cells
- When the user scrolls the list then the header should be pushed upwards that the two header-cells don't overlap.

The challenge here is the height of the header cell:

- If I set the height to 0 and uncheck `clip subviews` then that header cell is shown but does not get pushed away at the correct position.
- If I set the height of the header cell to the visual height then there is an empty space of that height *across* the whole width of the table which I don't want...

**Update 1:** I just realized that apple uses such a list for the search (grouped by messages, mails, contacts, calenders etc.). So my question basically is how can I tweak `UITableView` in order to behave like the grouped search results... :-)

[image]
<sub>(source: [mshcdn.com](http://6.mshcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/2photo.jpg))</sub>

Comment: @JimP It is an iPhone App. Do you think the approach would vary in case for the iPad?

Comment: Well it would not vary conceptually iPhone vs. iPad but practically it might because of the screen size.  I would suggest the Master-Detail Application template achieves what I understand to be your objective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** I created a project on github, which does exactly this. I have extracted all the relevant code for the behaviour into two classes ([`BBFloatingHeaderViewController`](https://github.com/besi/FloatingTableViewHeader/blob/master/BBFloatingHeaderTableViewController.h) & [`BBFloatingHeaderCell`](https://github.com/besi/FloatingTableViewHeader/blob/master/BBFloatingHeaderCell.h)). There is also an example project. I hope this is useful for others :-)

Here's the project: [besi/FloatingTableViewHeader](https://github.com/besi/FloatingTableViewHeader)

This is an excerpt from the readme:

> ## Floating UITableView headers
>
> These classes aim to copy the behaviour found in iOS built-in Spotlight search, where the search results are grouped by category and the icon of the respective category floats on the left side of the search results.
>
> ### Setup
>
> Check out the example project so see how to setup the classes.
>
> 1. Add the `.m` + `.h` files of `BBFloatingHeaderViewController` and `BBFloatingHeaderCell` to your project.
> 2. Create a TableView and set the Class of the ViewController to your subclass of `BBFloatingHeaderViewController`
> 3. Create the header cell in IB and set its class to your subclass of `BBFloatingHeaderCell`
> 4. Make sure that your floating header view is the topmost view in the `BBFloatingHeaderCell`'s view hierarchy.
>
> ### The result
>
> [Floating Headers http://i.minus.com/jyea3I5qbUdoQ.png](http://i.minus.com/jyea3I5qbUdoQ.png)

Comment: @Jim Thanks for the kudos. I created an example project on github. See my updated answer.

Comment: how to set the image of headet consume the whole section vertical size