# How to "lock" a view to scroll next to table cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to achieve something like Skype for iOS does, basically to keep a profile picture floating next to a users messages while scrolling.

What I did was to create a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass, and add a `UIImageView` out of the bounds of the actual frame.

In the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass

```
- (instancetype)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    //Check "y" position
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 40, 40)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile"];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:imageView];

    return self;
}
```

In the `UITableViewDelegate` object

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}
```

As you can see, the imageView starts exactly where the header finishes.

This actually (kinda') works, but the problem is when scrolling, the next image is not "pushing" the first one correctly, they overlap (which makes total sense).

Check the following [video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31675938/Untitled.mov) for a better understanding of the problem

I tried to look over the web, but apparently I didn't come up the exact term :). Any ideas?

**Update:**
As an update, what I want is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180272/uitableview-headers-on-the-left-side-of-sections-like-spotlight), The only difference is that I want to know if it is possible to achieve using `UITableHeaderFooterView`

Comment: Why don't you add a subview to the row? This would scroll with the row.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I want the subview not to scroll along with the cell :)

Comment: IMO you would be better off with a `UICollectionView`  and something like this: https://github.com/petec-blog/CollectionViewStickyHeaders

Comment: Thanks, I'll review that more in depth, but at a glance it seems to have the same issue.

Comment: Then I do not understand, what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple problem, your UIImageView isn't on the frame of the header, it should be inside of the header bounds

A simple way to test it is:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 80;
}
```

That will make a gap of 80 pixels between each section, that is another problem to solve, maybe setting a content inset for the tableView be enough.

Comment: Hey, thanks. But the "thats another problem" is the problem I want to solve haha. My idea of shifting the image out of the header is actually a partial  solution for that. I'll try the content inset thing, but I don't think it will work since the content inset is related of the scroll view. Having multiple sections will bring the problem back again :)